# Podman integration failed due to conmon older version in yocto build

Tags: docker, docker-compose, podman, podman-compose, podman-in-podman

As I am trying to integrate podman in yocto build system as already done in docker. For docker i haven't faced any issues just followed these steps: https://elinux.org/images/b/b4/03_integrating-docker-containers-in-yocto.pdf

I also refered this: https://docs.podman.io/en/latest/markdown/podman-system-service.1.html#run-the-command-in-a-systemd-service

I am using arm64 architecture.

But in podman integration I am facing issues which I am not able to resolve it.

```
root@spider:~# systemctl status podman

* podman.service - Podman API Service

     Loaded: loaded (/lib/systemd/system/podman.service; enabled; vendor preset: enabled)

     Active: failed (Result: exit-code) since Sat 2023-09-23 15:30:51 UTC; 2s ago
TriggeredBy: * podman.socket
       Docs: man:podman-system-service(1)
    Process: 464 ExecStart=/usr/bin/podman $LOGGING system service 
(code=exited, status=125)

   Main PID: 464 (code=exited, status=125)

 


spider systemd[1]: Starting Podman API Service...

spider systemd[1]: Started Podman API Service.

spider podman[464]: time="2023-09-23T15:30:51Z" level=warning msg="Failed to decode the keys [\"storage.options.override_kernel_check\" \"storage.options.thinpool.ostre...storage.conf\"."

spider podman[464]: time="2023-09-23T15:30:51Z" level=info msg="/usr/bin/podman filtering at log level info"

spider podman[464]: time="2023-09-23T15:30:51Z" level=warning msg="Conmon at /usr/bin/conmon invalid: outdated conmon version"

spider podman[464]: time="2023-09-23T15:30:51Z" level=warning msg="Conmon at /usr/bin/conmon is invalid: outdated conmon version"

spider podman[464]: Error: please update to v2.0.24 or later: outdated conmon version

spider systemd[1]: podman.service: Main process exited, code=exited, status=125/n/a

spider systemd[1]: podman.service: Failed with result 'exit-code'.
Hint: Some lines were ellipsized, use -l to show in full.
```

I tried to update the conmon using apt upgrade conmon but not able to fix this issue. Tried to find what other things required podman.sock and podman.service but haven't figured it out. Can you guys please help?
The service comes up for 3 second but it terminates after that. I need to run it for infinite time. Or does not drop off after starting the podman service.